# React Native: bind and 'this'?

Tags: reactjs, this, bind

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = { email: '', password: '', alert: 'Please Enter Your Email And Password' }


  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.setState({ alert: 'Please Try Again' });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .catch(() => {
            this.setState({ alert: 'Login/Registeration Failed.' });
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Button
            text={'Login'}
            onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
```

As you see in the last line of code, my button calls the function onButtonPress whenever my button is pressed. I also used .bind(this) to make the method bounded to the LoginForm component. Because as far as I know ES6 classes do not auto-bind methods to itself. But what does 'this' in the method onButtonPress() refer to if I wrote this.onButtonPress
instead of this.onButtonPress.bind(this) and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `bind` will define the value of `this` inside the bound function.

In your case you pass "this" (and not "foo" or "bar") because you want the `this` from `onButtonPress` to be the `this` of your `render`, which is the instance of your `LoginForm` class.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I think the question was what would the context (`this`) be in `onButtonPress()` if the code did not use `.bind()`.

Comment: Then it would be `undefined`. Because `onButtonPress` would not have any reference to its class.